# Looking for JS Regex that finds data between . and , or '

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have strings of the following type:

```
ns1.importantClassA,ns1.nonImportantClass
ns2.importantClassB'1[ns2.nonImportantClass1,ns2.nonImportantClass2]
```

I need to retrieve the names of the important Classes (importantClassA, importantClassB).

I have created the following code for the moment:

```
function getData(fullPath)
{
    var retVal = fullPath;
    var endIndex = retVal.indexOf(",");
    var endIndexOption2 = retVal.indexOf("`");
    if (endIndexOption2 != -1 && endIndexOption2<endIndex)
    {
        endIndex = endIndexOption2;
    }

    if (endIndex != -1)
    {
        var startIndex = retVal.lastIndexOf('.',endIndex);
        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            retVal = retVal.substr(startIndex+1,endIndex-startIndex-1);
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

but obviously a regex will simplify it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: your `nonImportantClass1` is also between `.` and `,` , so regex will also pick this accordingly , you need to give more specifications , if you wanna eliminate  `nonImportantClass1` in final result

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex :

```
/.(\w+?)[\,|\']/g
```

Code :

```
const regex = /.(\w+?)[\,|\']/g;
var str = "ns2.importantClassB'1[ns2.nonImportantClass1,ns2.nonImportantClass2]";
var found = str.match(regex);
if (found !== null) {
    var max = found.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        found[i] = found[i].replace(/[,|'|.]/g, "");

    }
}
```

match() returns all strings matched in the regex (the problem though is it includes the '.' and "'" or "," that's why I looped each match and replaced those characters with "").

If you can find a better regex you might be able to omit the loop part!